# Bootstrap Stylus не работает

Tags: css, gulp, stylus

Доброго времени суток. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Вроде делаю все по гайду. из за чего ошибка? 
использую
https://github.com/maxmx/bootstrap-stylus

[image: gulp task]

[image: stylus file]

Answer (score 1):

В ошибке написано, что в файле `test/project/node_modules/bootstrap-styl/bootstrap/mixins.styl` в строке 13 ошибка. Это может быть из-за отсутствия файла в папке `test/project/node_modules/bootstrap-styl/bootstrap/mixins/hide-text`. Добавьте этот файл или удалите строку 13 в файле `mixins.styl`. Обратите внимание на пути, они могут казаться одинаковыми.

Comment: но это npm пакет, будет не правильно, если я буду его изменять

Comment: Переустановите пакет может не все скачалось